# How to trigger a Jenkins pipeline build for every artifact uploaded to Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have set the Artifact Trigger for a jenkins multi branch pipeline and the schedule is as follows

[image]

I have noticed that the Artifactory Trigger only triggers 1 Jenkins build based on the last/ latest artifact uploaded after polling even if there were multiple artifacts uploaded within the polling period/ time i.e within the 10mins of the polling schedule in the above picture, but I would like a build to be triggered for every artifact that is uploaded to the "watched paths". Can someone please help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered similar issues. One solution / workaround was to create a "handler" pipeline for our main pipeline. This would effectively be the pipeline triggered by artifacts, and would then have logic to split apart the triggers , and for each artifact, would trigger our main pipeline, passing in the parameters required from properties on the artifact.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Can you please share the logic that you used to split apart the triggers in the handler pipeline or any info on how you achieved the same?